# Empty toolbox and properties window in VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio, toolbox

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2022 few weeks ago, from the first time I open it I found that both toolbox and properties window are empty
What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Right-click on the Toolbox, select 'Choose Items...'.  In the UI dialogue displayed, choose the items appropriate for your project (WinForms or WPF).

Answer (score 3):

I am also facing the same problems. But in respect of toolbox, I right-clicked inside the empty toolbox and chose 'Reset toolbox' option in the context menu. After this, the toolbox items appeared. But in respect of the properties window, I am still searching for a solution.

Comment: That did the trick for me. In my case, the properties window was working fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

When I first opened visual studio, I created the CMake project. Both the toolbox and property pages were empty. Resetting the toolbox did not help. Then, I closed and opened the visual studio and created a new empty project. With this, I am able to view the property pages(Rightclick Solution in Solution Explorer -> Properties). And for the toolbox, it was still empty. After few trials of 'reset toolbox', I did right click and 'show all' option. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old. Click "View" then click "Toolbox" (If the toolbox is entirely missing)

If it's not, then right-click inside of the toolbox, click "Reset Toolbox" then wait for it to re-initialize. It takes a little while.